# Are virtually all major distributed computing projects attempting to solve problems in NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, distributed-computing, np-complete

Here's a huge list of distributed computing projects: http://distributedcomputing.info/projects.html

After a quick skim, I couldn't find any projects which weren't attempting to solve problems in NP (the search problem version). Does anyone know of any projects tackling things outside of NP?

Also, are there any distributed computing projects that are attempting to solve problems in classes faster than NP, like in P perhaps?

I'm trying to figure out if there's some very general class of search problem which all or virtually all major distributed computing projects are polynomial-time reducible too. I wonder if the answer to this question is "anything that's NP-complete."

I wasn't sure if this should be on here, but since it involves understanding real-world software, I thought it would be within scope.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to relate directly to code and coding and is off-topic here. Try with [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).